# How to alarmofire parsing json store in Array

Tags: swift, swift3

I have response from server I want to filter it and store in array using swift. Please help how to do it.

```
self.countryArrayvalue = (json?["list"] as! [Dictionary<String, Any>] as! NSArray) as! [Dictionary<String, Any>]
```

now i want to get country name from this `self.countryArrayvalue` and store in array.

Response is:

```
{
  "error": false,
  "error_code": 200,
  "list": [
    {
      "country_id": "1",
      "country_name": "Afghanistan",
      "iso_code": "AF"
    },
    {
      "country_id": "2",
      "country_name": "Aland Islands",
      "iso_code": "AX"
    },
    {
      "country_id": "3",
      "country_name": "Albania",
      "iso_code": "AL"
    } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making too many casting instead of single one.

```
self.countryArrayvalue = json?["list"] as! [[String: Any]]
```

Now to get array of country name try like this way.

```
self.countryNamesArray = self.countryArrayvalue.flatMap { $0["country_name"] as? String }
```